# why does dict({4:None}) returns {4: None} but dict([{4,None}]) returns {None: 4} in Python 3.11

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.11

I was fiddling with dict() and found out that when I do

`>>> dict({4:None})` it returns
`{4: None}` which is expected but,

when I try converting a list containing a nested set `[{4,None}]`

`>>> dict([{4,None}])`
returns
`{None: 4}` which genuinely unexpected.

Then I checked that it only happens with few integers. That is crazy.

e.g. `dict([{5,None}])` returns `{None: 5}`

`dict([{6,None}])` returns `{None: 6}`

`dict([{7,None}])` returns `{None: 7}`

although

`dict([{8,None}])` returns `{8: None}`

`dict([{9,None}])` returns `{9: None}`

Can anyone answer this? I am using Python 3.11

Comment: `{4,None}` is a `set` of 4 and None. A Set is an unordered collection of data. It might be better to use list of tuple or list, e.g. `dict([(4,None), (5, None)])` or `dict([[4,None], [5, None]])`

Answer (score 2):

The [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) built-in supports three ways of creating a dict:

```
class dict(**kwargs)
class dict(mapping, **kwargs)
class dict(iterable, **kwargs)
```

The first way is like `dict(a=0, b=1)`. The second way is similar like `dict({4:None})` used in the question. The third way is the one of interest here, the normal usage is providing an iterable of key and value pairs, e.g. like this:

```
>>> data = [("a", 0), ("b", 1), ("c", 2)]
>>> dict(data)
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

By using a list containing a set of two elements, you're accidentally triggering that code path. Sets are not ordered, so whether you get back `{None: 4}` or `{4: None}` here is arbitrary.